# Collision between `siunitx`, `cellspace` and the letters 'd' and 'e'

Tags: siunitx, debugging, cellspace

The following code fails to compile. It can be made to compile by any of the following changes

1. Removing `\usepackage{siunitx}`
2. Removing the `S` from from the `tabular` column specifiers
3. Replacing the `d` in the table with any text that contains neither the letter `d` nor the letter `e`.

.

```
\documentclass{minimal}    

\usepackage{cellspace}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{Sc}
  d
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The error is

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! siunitx error: "invalid-number"
! 
! Invalid numerical input 'd'.
! 
! See the siunitx documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  

l.9     \end
            {tabular}
```

The error only occurs if three conditions are satisfied

1. The letter `d` or `e` is present in the table,
2. in a column marked with `S`,
3. while the `siunitx` package is loaded

How on earth should I go about debugging this?

Comment: Yes, it's not a valid number: what are you expecting to happen?

Comment: @JosephWright I'm expecting whatever is there (where the `d` appears in the sample code) to be typeset ... i.e. exactly what happens with *any* text that doesn't contain `d` or `e`. Try replacing the `d` with `a` and you'll see what I expect to happen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `siunitx` package uses `S` for the numerical alignment column type: it moves the `cellspace` one to `C`. You therefore have a numerical column but with a `d`: that's an exponent marker, but with no numerical content it's an invalid number (something like `1d4` would be valid; `D` and `e`/`E` are also exponent markers).  If you want a `cellspace` column, use `C`; if you want an `siunitx` `S` column, provide a full number or wrap the text in braces (so it is not parsed).

Comment: Since the update from last summer, `cellspace` gives  users the possibility to use another pre-specifier for ‘cellspaced’ columns via a loading option `[column= some letter]`, but it can't be used with `siunitx`, since the `C` pre-specifier is hard-coded. Would it be possible to let the user  have the choice with this option?

Comment: For completeness, the solution to this problem is described in section 7.11 of the `siunitx` manual.

Comment: @Bernard I've adjust that (last week I think), thought I still think `cellspace` = `C` makes most sense ...

Comment: @JosephWright:  Thanks for the adjustment. With `C`, a problem might come for someone using  also `tabulary`, let alone many people defining as `C` a centred + various specifications column type. That's why I thought useful for  the end-user  to have a choice.